# How can I delete a repo within a repo?

Tags: git, github

I have a project with a git repository and have created another repository in one of the subfiles by mistake. When I use `git remote -v` I see they have different urls. Now what I have in the subfolder doesn't match what has been pushed to github. How can I get my local repo to pull the my file from github and push to the original repository in the future.

Comment: `pull the my file` ...what does this mean?

Comment: I think deleting the inner `.git` directory will solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git remote remove xxx` can remove the "bad repo"
and `git fetch goodremote` will fetch latest.

Your best bet is:

```
git checkout -b branchyouwant goodremote/branchyouwant
```

I would however recommend adding goodremote as `origin` if it isn't already like so:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com...
```

Another easier option is to `rm` that directory and re-clone the repo from github.com

Comment: Thanks. Re-cloning into another directory fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly confused by your question.

If everything in your remote repo is correct, you should just be able to pull from it and it will overwrite whatever is in your local.

If you're having problems pushing to your remove repo, do a git push --set-upstream  and it should push to that branch everytime. Might need a -u flag somewhere in there